# Composer error when using a self-hosted GitHub Actions runner

Tags: php, github, composer-php, github-actions

I'm trying to switch from GitHub hosted actions runners to my own GitHub actions runner. I have a server with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on which I have installed GitHub actions runner as a service.

However, when running `composer` commands on my runner in my GitHub workflow in my repo, I'm getting a cryptic error message which doesn't make a whole lot of sense:

```
The HOME or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be set for composer to run correctly.
```

`$HOME` is set on my server, since when I SSH in and run `echo $HOME` I see the output for my home directory. The GitHub actions runner is also running as the same user I SSH into the server as.

So how can I configure this correctly for the actions runner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I killed all actions processes and restarted the service on my server and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Could you please specify which processes you've killed and what service you're restarted?

Comment: The actions runner can be run as a service, so that is the service I stopped and I killed any processes that mentioned actions

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When running `./run.sh` as a normal user, `composer validate` works. When starting the service using `./svc.sh start` which is required to run as root,  `composer validate` fails. Any idea?

Comment: Make sure the the service runs under a non root user by running `svc.sh install githubactionsrunner` and making sure the `_diag` directory is owned by the `githubactionsrunner` user.